# Android Studio. Изменить размер картинки добавленной к TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Добавил картинку к `TextView` с помощью `android:drawableBottom`. Меня интересует, могу ли я изменить размер картинки не меняя ее исходника и не разбивая `TextView` отдельно на `TextView` и `ImageView`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, не можете. Надо или исходник менять или разбивать на 2 вьюхи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два свойства scaleX и scaleY.

В приведенном ниже коде изображение и текст уменьшаются на 30%. Следовательно, вы должны увеличить размер шрифта с таким количеством `sp`, чтобы при изменении размера (масштабировании) он соответствовал тому `sp`, который вы предпочитаете.

Пример. Если я установлю шрифт на 18, то 30% из 18 будут 5,4sp, так что примерно это значение, на которое я нацелен, потому что при масштабировании оно станет 13sp.

```
<TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
```

Поэтому вы можете побаловаться с этими свойствами. Но я бы вам этого крайне не рекомендовал. Это легкий способ *"выстрелить себе в ногу"*.

Поэтому как вам ответили в комментарии - лучше либо сделайте 2 отдельные View, либо создайте картинку нужного вам размера. Если вы не хотите всегда делать 2 отдельные View то можете написать свою кастомную View и инкапсулировать там эту логику.